# An element in a sequence returns a string

Tags: r

I am making a simple sequence.  Why is this true?

```
Browse[1]> seq(7.4, 12.7, 0.001)[2] == 7.401
[1] FALSE
Browse[1]> seq(7.4, 12.7, 0.001)[2] == '7.401'
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Never use `==` to compare numerics in R. Check [this](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a floating point (tolerance) error. Try,

```
round(seq(7.4, 12.7, 0.001)[2], 3) == 7.401
#TRUE
```